# PythonAnywhere Issue: Your processes have been killed because a process exceeded RAM Limit

Tags: python, django, spacy, pythonanywhere

I am getting this warning email from PythonAnywhere on every single request to my website. I am using spaCy and Django and have just upgraded my account. Everything seems to work fine, though. Except I am receiving warning emails, that is. I have only 2 GB RAM on my local machine and it can run my app along with a few other apps too without any issues. Then why is 3 GB RAM not enough on PythonAnywhere? (I also have 3 GB disc space on PythonAnywhere, of which only 27% is used up.)

I have tried searching for the answers on their forum and on the internet in general but I have not got any clue about the issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question for PythonAnywhere's support team.

Answer (score 2):

If your initial requests on the PythonAnywhere webapp works fine (ie. your code successfully allocates say 2GB RAM and returns a result), and you see the results correctly, but you receive emails about processes exceeding the RAM limit, then perhaps you have processes that are left hanging around, not cleaned up, and they are accumulating until they slowly get killed? Can you correspond this with the # of kill messages you get vs the number of times you hit the webapp and get a result? My theory would be corroborated if there are significantly less kill messages vs the hits for that particular model endpoint.